# Lazy Loading to named page-router-outlet

Tags: angular, nativescript

I'm trying to create a navigation scenario with two named page-router-outlets in a way similar to the project that can be found here: https://github.com/NativeScript/login-tab-navigation-ng. The difference is I don't want to route to a tabbed navigation. I just want to route the entire app to a second named page-router-outlet.

I've got the login router working but when I try to navigate to the second router-outlet, I get an error that says the route cannot be found. I'm not sure what I've missed in the routing. The purpose of the second router outlet is to create a static navigation bar on the top of the home html page that doesn't need to be recreated in other modules. There are other elements that I want on every page too.

I created a playground example here: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=kh7fog&v=21

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Basically you want to have your nested router to be loaded lazily? You seem to have typo on front house module, also you are navigating using accurate path in home page, it suppose to be relative.

Comment: Yes I want modules to be lazily loaded into the nested router. I can get to the home page but that is in the default router. I'm unable to reroute and load the fronthouse module into nested router.

Comment: @Manoj I don't see a typo in the fronthouse module. Will you tell me where you saw it?

Comment: Also I edited the playground to add a relative path to the router navigation in the home.component.ts, but I still get the error that it cannot find the route. Here's the updated playground: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=kh7fog&v=35

Answer (score 1):

There are various bugs & typos you have in your code,

- You had never declared FronthouseModule. I guess it was a typo on `fronthouse.module.ts`, I renamed HomeModule to FronthouseModule.
- You do not need outlet name / empty outlet component etc., those are used in tab based routing where there will be more than one router outlet at same level. In your case you have one router outlet at a time even if it's nested.
- I had to update the syntax for loadChildren, used latest Angular syntax just like you have in app routing module
- You can not have more than one UI element without wrapping it in a layout. You had a label and page router outlet without a layout in your original code. I wrapped them with GridLayout, so both will be visible.

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=kh7fog&v=37)

Comment: Some of those errors were just in the playground not my app, but the key to solving my problem in the app were not naming the outlet, not using the outlet name and not using the empty outlet component. Thanks for your help!